# Creating connection in QT for use in separate thread

Tags: database, multithreading, qt

Well, this is much discussed question, but still not clear:
I need to use a database connection in separate thread. When I create this thread, I know all valid connection parameters (because I already have one valid connection).

So, i wish to clone this (valid) connection, try open it, and if its ok - pass it to constructor of my thread worker object, and then run a thread (In this case i'm sure, that my thread will work).

The another approach is - to pass just connection params into constructor, and establish new connection just after thread runs (within QThread.Started(), for example). So, I need a way to inform ctrator thread about fails, if any.

The first approach looks much easier, and works fine, but contradicts to [this statement](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module). So, **the question is** - is it just a luck, and I have to follow the second approach anyway, **or** the Qt docs only forbids me of using same connection from thwo or more different threads, and my (first) approach will work fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt does not forbid you from using same database connection from multiple threads. That limitation is from the database drivers. If you want to be reasonably safe, open, use and close database connections in one thread only. If you want more flexibility, you'll have to take a look at each of the Qt's SQL plugins and the drivers they are using to find out their individual limitations with respect to threads.

Comment: Thanks alot. If so, and also - if I'm using **concrete** driver,  I've no need of any "universal" (driver invariant) solution, and my tests works fine - I'll beleive, it will works... until first crash =) Thats right, I should learn more about postgres libpq...